# using xlrd in Windows Forms with Ironpython

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, winforms, ironpython

I am pretty new to Windows Forms and Ironpython and I have to connect a python script that reads the column values of an excel file and returns a list to a windows Form, so I did a class for doing so:

```
class Python_Script
    {
        private ScriptEngine engine;
        private ScriptScope scope;
        private ScriptSource source;
        public Python_Script(string name)
        {
            engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            scope = engine.CreateScope();
            string str = @"script_route" + name;
            engine.ExecuteFile(@str, scope);
        } 

        public List<string> Col_Values(int sheet, int col)
        {
            List<string> result;
            dynamic col_values = scope.GetVariable("Col_Values");
            result = col_values(sheet, col);
            return result;
        }
```

And when mi form is initialized I do this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        List<string> test_col = new List<string>();
        Python_Script my_py = new Python_Script("script_leer_excel.py");

        public Form2()
        {
            test_col =  my_py.Col_Values(0,0);
        }
```

This is my python script

```
import sys
import xlrd

loc = ("excel_route")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

def Col_Values(sheet, col):
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(sheet)
    result = sheet.col_values(col)
    return result
```

But when I run the code I get the error:
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named xlrd'

I have no idea on how to install the xlrd module in Ironpython, I installed it with the command promt for python 3.8 and my python enviroment in visual strudio tells me I am running python 3.8 
[Visual studio python enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chFj7.png)